# When a recursive function returns itself to a caller, who makes that subsequent call?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
async function parentFunction() {
    try {
        await taskFunction(xyz);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

async function taskFunction(xyz) {
    try {
        const done = await someAsyncTask(xyz);
        if !(done) {
            return taskFunction(xyz); // recursion
        }
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

To help me better understand what is going on behind the scenes, when the task function returns itself to the caller (because there are more tasks to complete), behind the scenes, is the task function returning itself to the caller and the caller then makes that subsequent call? Or is the task function calling itself and then returning the boolean through this chain of calls?

Comment: The recursive `taskFunction(xyz)` is inside `taskFunction` itself, so it's the `taskFunction` that performs the recursive call, not the caller

Comment: @CertainPerformance is the use of `return` then a bit misleading since the way I read it is that the task function returns that subsequent call to the caller, and the caller then makes that call. If I omit the `return` will it still function the same?

Comment: No. In a `return` statement, the expression on the right-hand side is completely evaluated **before** the containing function actually returns. The recursive call is finished when the `return` happens, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy I see, so the right-hand side is evaluated (the task function runs again) and this could happen `n` times until finally it returns `true` and that is ultimately returned to the parent function?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's why in cases where recursion is broken, like due to a bug, there can be stack overflow errors: there are too many calls "piled up" on top of one another.

Comment: @Pointy I don't know if I'm allowed to ask this tangential question but what is the tool of choice in JS for putting a small delay on each recursive call so the server doesn't overheat with too many rapid calls?

Comment: Since you're already in an async function, something like this would do: `const wait = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));` and then before the recursive call `await wait(howLongInMilliseconds); return taskFunction(xyz);`, or make a simple recursion wrapper, e.g. `const recurseWithDelay = ({ fn, delay = 10 }, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(async () =>resolve(await fn(...args)), delay));` then call with `return await recurseWithDelay({ fn: taskFunction }, xyz);`. You shouldn't be too worried about server load during recursion though, you'll be fine.

Comment: @kidcoder "delay" in JavaScript isn't really the way things work. You could use a timer to schedule the calls in the future, but then (for technical reasons) it really wouldn't be "recursion" any more. Also, I wouldn't worry about the server CPU, unless you're doing extremely complicated computations. If you are, the right thing to do is look into a better algorithm or (my favorite) find a way to avoid computing it completely.